# Hi, I am beginning to learn how to code. I am trying to make an ascii art hourglass in python using for loops and nested for loops

Tags: python

I am trying to make an hour glass and I have the bottom portion of it done, but I cant quite get the top

So I'm using nested for loops basically print the top half of the hourglass which looks like an upside down pyramid. I got the code down but cant indent the colons perfectly so they come down in pyramid form

```
num = 8
print('|"""""""""|')
for i in range(num,0,-1):
    for x in range(0,num-i):
        print(" ",end ="")
    for x in range(0,i):
        print(":", end ="")
    print()
```

I want my expected output to be:

[image: 1]

Comment: please edit your question; adding your expected output

Comment: @JoeIddon I hit edit, Where do I i find the expected output at?

Comment: That is for you to come up with! What would you like your code to print ideally... Just write this in the code format (4 space indented) in the edit section of your question, then we can modify your code to produce this output. I.e. by "expected" I mean "what do you want this to do???".

Comment: @JoeIddon I added a link to a screen shot of what i want my code to print out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just trying to make some ASCII art, which I would approach using text formatting. You can use the fact that `':' * 5` -> `':::::'` as well as the `'{}'.format()` syntax for formatting strings to print a varying amount of colons with each print statement! Here is an example I made that works well if you specify an odd number of rows to print:

```
rows = 9
for i in range(int(rows / 2)):
    print('{}{}'.format(' ' * i, ':' * (rows - (2 * i))))
for i in range(int(rows / 2), -1, -1):
    print('{}{}'.format(' ' * i, ':' * (rows - (2 * i))))
```

Output:

```
:::::::::
 :::::::
  :::::
   :::
    :
   :::
  :::::
 :::::::
:::::::::
```

Comment: yes! this is exactly what im trying to make, I updated my title so it specifies that. Sorry im new to this website also. Is there a way I can make that using nested for loops?

Comment: To quote "The Zen of Python": `Flat is better than nested.`. This is one of the main python ideals, so I cannot understand why you desire to go against it...Yes I am sure you could do this with nested `for` loops, but you would lose readability very quickly and there is not really anything to gain from it

Comment: I have to make this program using for loops. I see how its much easier to read the code you wrote compared to mine.

Comment: @EndriRama This code is using `for` loops already, so your requirement is satisfied!

Comment: I see, I will run and read your code to better understand it and see if I can write something like that myself. Ill keep you updated